# Android SideBySide Text View- if first one is too large second one go to the next line

Tags: android, textview

i have two text view that are side by side:

```
<TextView1><TextView2>
```

i want if textview2 is too large textview1 go to next line:

```
<TextView2IsToooooooooooooooooooLarge>
<Textview1>
```

Comment: You have to do it dynamically. Listen `TextView2` with `onTextChanged`, when you reach the limit change properties based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

If text you want to set is longer than it will go to the next line it self.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="4"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."></TextView>
```

Hope this help you out.